# Getting error while passing a function as a parameter within a class

Tags: c++, arduino, nodemcu

I am trying to do something with [ESPAsyncWebServer](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer) library. I have a class in ServerManager.h called MyServerManager. When I compile the code I get this error. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

25:67 is the bold word "**this**"

> src\ServerManager.cpp: In lambda function:
> src\ServerManager.cpp:25:67: error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function
> request->send(LittleFS, "/status.html", String(), false, [**this**](const String &var) -> String { return statusProcessor(var); });

*** [.pio\build\nodemcuv2\src\ServerManager.cpp.o] Error 1

in ServerManager.cpp file

```
void MyServerManager::init()
{
    if (!LittleFS.begin())
    {
        Serial.println("Something went wrong while begin LittleFS");
    }

    server->on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send(LittleFS, "/status.html", String(), false, [this](const String &var) -> String { return statusProcessor(var); });
    });
    server->begin();
}

String MyServerManager::statusProcessor(const String &var)
{
    if (var == "NETWORK_NAME")
    {
        return WiFi.SSID();
    }
    else if (var == "SIGNAL_STRENGTH")
    {
        return String(WiFi.RSSI()) + " dBm";
    }

    return String();
}
```

in ServerManager.h file

```
#ifndef ServerManager_h
#define ServerManager_h
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

class MyServerManager
{
private:
    AsyncWebServer *server = NULL;
    AsyncWebSocket *ws = NULL;
    void notifyClients(const String *msg);
    void handleWebSocketMessage(void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len);
    void onEvent(AsyncWebSocket *server, AsyncWebSocketClient *client, AwsEventType type, void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len);
    void initWebSocket();
    String statusProcessor(const String &var);

public:
    MyServerManager(uint16_t port, const String url);
    ~MyServerManager();

    void init();
};

#endif
```

Comment: `this` can't be captured in lambdas arbitrarily.

Comment: what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `this` to the outer lambda capture list:

```
void MyServerManager::init()
{
    if (!LittleFS.begin())
    {
        Serial.println("Something went wrong while begin LittleFS");
    }
    //                       > vvvv <
    server->on("/", HTTP_GET, [this](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
        request->send(LittleFS, "/status.html", String(), false, [this](const String &var) -> String { return statusProcessor(var); });
    });
    server->begin();
}
```